# how to call viewpager from one button of viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

How can I call one view pager to another view pager?

https://github.com/mrleolink/SimpleInfiniteCarousel

I follow the code as above.

[image: view pager flow image]

If user click button 1 , it will call another infinite carousel view pager.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mf, container, false);

    final int pos = this.getArguments().getInt("pos");
    Button btn = (Button) l.findViewById(R.id.content);
    btn.setText("position:"+pos);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (pos == 0){
                //code something
                //how to call another view pager (similar as MyFragment).
            }
        }
    });


    MyLinearLayout root = (MyLinearLayout) l.findViewById(R.id.root);
    float scale = this.getArguments().getFloat("scale");
    root.setScaleBoth(scale);

    return l;
}

Comment: Do you want to replace your first viewpager with the second, on clicking the button?

Comment: Make second viewpager object to static and then on event of button click set current item of that static viewpager.